# Debugging 32-bit ActiveX control with Visual Studio 2008 and IE 10

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, activex, 32bit-64bit, internet-explorer-10

I am unable to hit breakpoints while debugging my 32-bit ActiveX control using Visual Studio 2008 when running with IE 10.

After thorough research, I've learned that IE 10 will only run in 32-bit mode when HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth is set to a non-zero value.  This enables me to run the 32-bit ActiveX control.  However, this also disables the ability to hit breakpoints when debugging with Visual Studio, because in order to debug with breakpoints, this value must be zero.  As stated in other questions/responses: "For debugging purposes, you may find it helpful to set HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth = 0 (DWORD).  This will disable process separation in IE."

This creates a catch-22 scenario, because in order to debug, TabProcGrowth must be zero, but in order to get IE 10 to run in 32-bit mode, TabProcGrowth must be non-zero.

Any suggestions for what I might do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How to debug C++ in the IE.10 + WIN8 64bit + VS2008:

1. Keep TabProcGrowth with Medium (does not change !!)
2. Setting VS2008 OCX project Debugging with command C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,Attach = Yes,Debugger Type=Native Only
3. Open the Internet Explore 10 form WIN8 taskbar.
4. key in the target ocx htm file path in the url of Internet Explorer 10. and press enter key to load htm.
5. enable IE.10 ActiveX mode.
6. When IE10 was ActiveX mode ready, run your VS2008 OCX procject that will attach IE10 with your break point.
7. Refresh IE.10 html again to start debug your ocx source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I found to debug a 32-bit ActiveX Control with VS2013 and IE10 (Win7 64-bit):

1. VS: set the OCX project debugging properties to : Command = C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, Attach = No.
2. Start the debugger in VS (IE10 has not been launched yet): if a warning message appears ("debugging information for 'iexplore.exe' cannot be found..."), select "yes" (continue debugging). IE10 should have been launched now.
3. In VS menu, go to Debug > Attach to Process: please note the IDs of the existing "iexplore.exe" processes.
4. Open your ocx html file in IE10, then go back to VS's Attach to Process screen: refresh the process list, then Attach to the newly-appeared "iexplore.exe" process.
5. Refresh the ocx html page in IE10: this should bring your VS debugger to your first breakpoint.